# Parse value of $DatabasePassword from RT_SiteConfig.pm

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm writing a Bash shell script to backup our Request Tracker (RT) MySQL database on a daily basis. Instead of hard-coding the MySQL database user's password in the shell script I'd like to parse it from RT's RT_SiteConfig.pm file. The relevant line in RT_SiteConfig.pm looks like this:

```
Set($DatabasePassword , 'db_pw_here');
```

What would be the "cleanest" way of extracting only the string "db_pw_here" given the line above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "cleanest" way would be to write some Perl code to use the RT API to extract the value of `DatabasePassword`.  I don't have access to an RT instance right now to try this out but it shouldn't be terribly difficult.

You could probably integrate a one-line Perl program into your bash script to get the value, something like:

```
perl -MRT::Config -e 'print $RT::Config::DatabasePassword'
```

Please note that this command line is completely fictional.  Read the docs to find the actual invocation.

Now, less clean but probably perfectly effective would be to use `sed` to extract the information:

```
sed -n "/Set(\$DatabasePassword/ s/.*'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p"
```